# How to stop auto loading of previously opened notebooks

Tags: front-end

I'm trying to prevent Mathematica from opening previously opened notebooks when I start it up. I'm using version 10.0.0.0 on Mac OS X Yosemite. I've dug around in the preferences, and have tried setting `"ShowAtStartup"->"New Document"` and `"InitialUntitledNotebook"->False"`, but to no avail. The `"ShowAtStartup"` options don't seem to cover this issue.

Comment: I believe that this is a Mac OS-specific feature, and controlled (or disabled) through Mac OS rather than the application in question. Hence, I vote to close as off-topic since the issue is not specific to *Mathematica*. The question could be migrated to SuperUser.